# Technical name for a road "sliparound" lane

Tags: civil-engineering, terminology

What is the technical name for this kind of road segment?

[image]

I think the purpose of the lane on the right is to bypass the traffic lights at the intersection.

I've heard that kind of lane referred to as a *"sliparound"* lane. But I doubt that's the proper term.

**Edit:** The location is Ontario, Canada.

Comment: a slip around lane in my experience is more for an undivided two lane road where most of the time the the traffic at a turning point tends to go straight.  A low turn count will block the lane and cause a long delay for the cars behind.  A slip around land is therefore added at this point that allows the following cars to move over a lane at this turning point and continue straight.  Here is [an example near Kingston, Ontario, Canada](https://www.google.ca/maps/@44.2217297,-76.6706178,3a,75y,150.93h,78.29t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1s427WffjRaJVCWvLwy4Edmg!2e0!7i16384!8i8192?hl=en)

Comment: That name varies by country.

Comment: @SolarMike Thanks. Edited. The location is Ontario, Canada.

Comment: In Ireland it is a "filter lane".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name is the same as its purpose of service - "Exclusive Right Turn Lane", or "Right Turn Only Lane". Right turn lanes can significantly improve the capacity and level of service of signalized intersections.

Comment: also `dedicated right turn lane`

Comment: or right turn lane